# How can I transition from a runtime value to a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, optimization, variadic-functions

**Background**: I am writing some methods designed to be invoked on thousands of pixels in an image. The image can have different pixel formats (8 bit greyscale, 16 bits RGB, 24 bits RGB, etc.). It would be inefficient to re-check and branch on the pixel format for each pixel, thus I used C++ templates to generate a version of the whole process for each supported pixel format at compile time:

```
// Note: PixelFormat::Enum is an integral type.
template<PixelFormat::Enum PixelFormat>
struct EdgeTracer {

  Point FindInitialEdge(const void *pixels, int stride) {
    /* [...] */
  }

  std::vector<Point> TraceEdge(
    const void *pixels, int stride, const Point &initialEdge
  ) {
    /* [...] */
  }

};
```

Now I would like to create wrappers for these methods as plain C functions (for DLL export to .NET P/Invoke). Currently I'm doing this:

```
EXPORT Point DLLAPI FindInitialEdge(
  const void *pixels, int stride, PixelFormat::Enum pixelFormat
) {
  switch(pixelFormat) {
    case PixelFormat::Format8bppIndexed: {
      return EdgeTracer<PixelFormat::Format8bppIndexed>::FindInitialEdge(
        pixels, stride
      );
    }
    case PixelFormat::Format16bppRgb565: {
      return EdgeTracer<PixelFormat::Format16bppRgb565>::FindInitialEdge(
        pixels, stride
      );
    }
    case PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb888: {
      return EdgeTracer<PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb888>::FindInitialEdge(
        pixels, stride
      );
    }
    default: {
      // error handling
    }
  }
}

EXPORT PointBuffer *DLLAPI TraceEdge(
  const void *pixels, int stride, const Point *initialEdge,
  PixelFormat::Enum pixelFormat
) {
  // Nearly the same switch statement all over again
}
```

It is less than optimal having to go touch many unrelated functions when I want to add support for a new pixel format. Is there a clever way to avoid the redundant `switch` statements?

Here's is what I cooked up so far, but I haven't managed to make a variadic version of it:

```
template<typename T>
void invokeTemplated(
  PixelFormat::Enum pixelFormat, void (T::*method)(const void *pixels)
) {
  switch(pixelFormat) {
    case PixelFormat::Format16bppRgb555: {
      T<PixelFormat::Format16bppRgb555> instance;
      ((&instance)->*method)(pixels);
      break;
    }
    // [...]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. write an abstract interface mirroring your public interface, but just internal:

   ```
   class Interface {
   public:
     virtual ~Interface() {}
     virtual Point FindInitialEdge(const void *pixels, int stride) = 0;
     // other pure virtual methods here
   };
   ```
2. create a global mapping from pixel type to objects implementing this interface

   ```
   typedef std::unordered_map<PixelFormat::Enum, Interface*> ImplMap;
   ImplMap impls;
   ```
3. write all your public functions in the form:

   ```
   EXPORT Point DLLAPI FindInitialEdge(const void *pixels, int stride,
                                       PixelFormat::Enum pixelFormat) {
     ImplMap::iterator i = impls.find(pixelFormat);
     if (i != impls.end()) {
       return i->FindInitialEdge(pixels, stride);
     } else {
       // error handling
     }
   }
   ```
4. now you can either make your `EdgeTracer` template inherit from `Interface` and match up the virtual function definitions, or write a templated binding. The first is slightly less typing
5. and finally, to register all the concrete implementations, you just need a single place to do something like

   ```
   template <PixelFormat::Enum PF>
   bool register_format() {
     impls[PF] = new EdgeTracer<PF>;
   }

   bool initialized = register_format<PixelFormat::Format8bppIndexed>()
                    | register_format<PixelFormat::Format16bppRgb565>()
                    | register_format<PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb888>();
   ```

   just make sure you use the value of `initialized` somewhere so it can't be optimized away, and you have a single place to centrally register new formats.

Comment: That's a pretty good solution. The virtual methods would only have to encompass the public (high-level) methods and allow the code paths below to be inlined and optimized as the compiler pleases :)

Answer (score 1):

## Some Dirty Work Around

It's quite a dirty work-around, but could you not try that:

## First:

**You need A reminder of all class**

A define could do the trick:

```
# define ALL_MY_CLASS A,B,C //ect....
```

## Secondly:

All your class should have the same structure:

class A{//same for B,C ...
public:
 static const PixelFormat::enum e= PixelFormat::Format8bppIndexed/* associated enum value */;
 void methode_a();//or even your ::FindInitialEdge
};

## Then

**You should browse beetwen them**

```
int test_all_types_for_initial_edge( f) { // here you depack all your possible class
  return (test_types_for_initial_edge<ALL_MY_CLASS>(f));
};

template<typename current, typename second, typename ...elses>
int test_types_for_initial_edge(PixelFormat::enum ee) {
  if (ee == current ::e)//you test if the current tested class  match the enum
   return (EdgeTracer< current >::FindInitalEdge(/* do your stuff */);
 return (test_types_for_initial_edge(ee));
}

template<typename current>
int test_types_for_initial_edge(PixelFormat::enum ee) {
  if (ee == current ::e)//you test if the current tested class  match the enum
   return (EdgeTracer< current >::FindInitalEdge(/* do your stuff */);
 return (DEFAULT_VALUE); //or throw whatever
}
```

## What's the improvement of this (quite dirty) workaround

I think a bit of sfinae and check at pre-compil (if the class as a static_const enum... or the wanted method... ect...) could be quite good... 
But! If you want to keep updated your code, all you have to do is modifying the `ALL_MY_CLASS` define!

## By the way...

I don"t think that's totally compile (that's mainly correct but some part are pseudo-code) if you want some other help (like adding type_traits and amelioring a bit this work around just ask it ^^)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in "void* pixels". If you had a specific type for your pixels (8bits, RGBA, etc...), you could remove the switch and implement a function for each type.

If you use template functions, the compiler will resolve automatically the type when you use your pointer, and call the right function.

Comment: Sorry, but no. There are multiple pixel formats sharing the same pointer type (eg. 16 bpp grayscale, 16 bpp 5-5-5, 16 bpp 5-6-5). If each pixel format had a unique data type (could be achieved with custom pixel structures), I would then have to export a separate C function for each supported pixel format, which would increase the effort of adding new pixel formats event further ;-)

Comment: Just to provide some more explanation, the general idea is to write the pixel processing methods just once (with void * or std::uint8_t * or whatever) and then do things that are different between pixel formats through a lean structure that makes it easy to add new pixel formats: http://pastebin.com/mrxirQHD